# Dynamic table-width doesn't adjust properly

Tags: css, html-table, width, contenteditable, nested-table

I'm trying to build a genealogy tree with HTML tables (and nested tables). It should, ultimately be editable by the user using contenteditable, and the nested cells should resize accordingly.

However, to my mystery, when I edit the cells, they resize far too fast and too much. Why so?

The outer table keeps everything under control, so sizes are fixed using

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

The nested table cells, on the other hand are only specified via

```
margin:auto;
```

Every cell's width is set individually via percentage, and it looks perfect before editing. Not so after.

DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/KtB6C/
Try editing the Father or Mother cell.

I know this is a "fix-my-code" problem, but any help is appreciated.